# How to display images in Flask when src is given by function?

Tags: python, html, image, flask

Basically, i have a function that returns valid img sources (ex: https://image.prntscr.com/image/5P0nCp55SKe-WJTKjhCwsg.png)

When i try to display that image on html using flask, the image won't appear but a small icon of a image will be there, if i right click the icon and click "Open in new tab" it shows me the image but it just won't work on the html

My flask code:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, redirect, url_for, request
import LightHub # My other script that contains the function

app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route('/')
def index():
  return render_template('server.html', source=LightHub.crawl())

app.run(debug=True)
```

My HTML code (in the templates folder):

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Random Lightshot</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
</head>
<body>
    <div class="prints" align="middle">
        <img src="{{source}}" align="middle">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

output: https://i.stack.imgur.com/umyIv.jpg

Comment: If your functions returns the string "https://image.prntscr.com/image/5P0nCp55SKe-WJTKjhCwsg.png", then your code works for me. Maybe try hard reloading your webpage with "Cmd + Shift + R". Look in the source make sure ```href``` is what you want. Try a different browser. Just some suggestions.

Comment: Your HTML is out of order.

Comment: the function generates a random url from prnt.sc, checks if the url is valid and then gets the src from the html using selenium, the function will always return a string that is a valid src, but when i try to put it in the HTML as a image using the variable source (that has the src in it) the image will fail to appear, i tried hard reloading but it didn't work, also, what did you mean by saying "Look in the source make sure href is what you want."?

Comment: @KlausD. i just tried the HTML only with the img, it still won't work, unfortunately

Comment: The issue seems to with your HTML rather than Flask/Python. In your HTML, you need to have the `div class="prints"` line inside the `body`. I've added a code sample here - https://pastebin.com/RPxbdnfn.

Comment: @SaiprasadBalasubramanian even with your HTML code the image won't show up, i'm convinced that's not an function error because when i print the same variable, it returns a string that is a valid src for a img, i can't understant why this isn't working...

Comment: @ZeroMeia Could you post a screenshot of the actual HTML output through Flask?

Comment: @SaiprasadBalasubramanian https://imgur.com/IGY0mnY

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I try this,

```py
from flask import Flask, render_template

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('server.html', source='https://image.prntscr.com/image/5P0nCp55SKe-WJTKjhCwsg.png')
```

it works.

That probably means that `LightHub.crawl()` is not returning what you think it is. I believe you can verify that by running something like this:

```
assert LightHub.crawl() == 'https://image.prntscr.com/image/5P0nCp55SKe-WJTKjhCwsg.png'
```

I suspect that if you add that assert to your function, you'll find that it fails.